My website use html2pdf(javascript) to generate pdf from html but have issues of download on android webview: kotlin
My website use html2pdf(javascript) to generate pdf from html but have issues of download on android webview: kotlin. When I want to click download in my webview which display my website button it just crash. I was hoping from you guys who experience why it happened and how to overcome this? I'm still beginner of this android studio development.
In the website(javascript):

function generatePDF(){
    var station_element = document.getElementById('station_content');
    var inspect_element = document.getElementById('inspect_content');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    // Delay execution for 500 milliseconds (adjust as needed)
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (station_element) {
            var opt = {
                margin: 50,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 5, width: 1300 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(station_element).save();
        } else if (inspect_element) {
            var opt = {
                margin: 60,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(inspect_element).save();
        }
    }, 500); // 500 milliseconds delay
}


Android studio: MainActivity.kt
package com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var webUrl = "https://smartappx.site"
    private val multiplePermissionId = 14
    private val multiplePermissionNameList =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            arrayListOf()
        } else {
            arrayListOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            )
        }

    private var isLoaded = false
    private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false

    private val networkConnectivityObserver: NetworkConnectivityObserver by lazy {
        NetworkConnectivityObserver(this)
    }

    private val loadingDialog: Dialog by lazy { Dialog(this) }

    private val mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy {
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_layout)
        loadingDialog.window!!.setLayout(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false)
        loadingDialog.show()

        val setting = mainBinding.webView.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        setting.allowFileAccess = true
        setting.domStorageEnabled = true
        setting.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        setting.supportMultipleWindows()

        val snackbar =
            Snackbar.make(mainBinding.root, "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Wifi") { startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)) }

        networkConnectivityObserver.observe(this) {
            when (it) {
                Status.Available -> {
                    if (snackbar.isShown) {
                        snackbar.dismiss()
                    }
                    mainBinding.swipeRefresh.isEnabled = true
                    if (!isLoaded) loadWebView()
                }
                else -> {
                    showNoInternet()
                    snackbar.show()
                    mainBinding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        }

        mainBinding.swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            if (!isLoaded) {
                loadWebView()
            } else {
                setProgressDialogVisibility(false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setProgressDialogVisibility(visible: Boolean) {
        if (visible) {
            loadingDialog.show()
        } else {
            loadingDialog.dismiss()
            mainBinding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    private fun showNoInternet() {
        isLoaded = false
        setProgressDialogVisibility(false)
        gone(mainBinding.webView)
        visible(mainBinding.noInternet.noInternetRL)
    }

    private fun loadWebView() {
        gone(mainBinding.noInternet.noInternetRL)
        visible(mainBinding.webView)
        mainBinding.webView.loadUrl(webUrl)
        mainBinding.webView.setDownloadListener {
            url,
            userAgent,
            contentDisposition,
            mimeType,
            contentLength ->
            Log.d("Url", url.trim())
            Log.d("userAgent", userAgent)
            Log.d("contentDisposition", contentDisposition)
            Log.d("mimeType", mimeType)
            Log.d("contentLength", contentLength.toString())
            if (checkMultiplePermission()) {
                download(url.trim(), userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength)
            }
        }
        mainBinding.webView.webViewClient =
            object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    setProgressDialogVisibility(true)
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                }

                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?,
                ): Boolean {
                    val url = request?.url.toString()
                    view?.loadUrl(url)
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    isLoaded = true
                    webUrl = url!!
                    setProgressDialogVisibility(false)
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                }

                override fun onReceivedError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?,
                    error: WebResourceError?,
                ) {
                    isLoaded = false
                    setProgressDialogVisibility(false)
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (mainBinding.webView.canGoBack()) {
                    mainBinding.webView.goBack()
                } else {
                    showToastExit()
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }

    private fun showToastExit() {
        when {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce -> {
                finish()
            }
            else -> {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Click Back Again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                    .postDelayed({ doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false }, 2000)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun download(
        url: String,
        userAgent: String,
        contentDisposition: String,
        mimeType: String,
        contentLength: Long
    ) {
        val folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/Image")
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs()
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
        request.setMimeType(mimeType)
        val cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie)
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
        )
        val fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)
        request.setTitle(fileName)
        request.setNotificationVisibility(
            DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
        )
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            "Image/$fileName"
        )
        val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }

    private fun checkMultiplePermission(): Boolean {
        val listPermissionNeeded = arrayListOf<String>()
        for (permission in multiplePermissionNameList) {
            if (
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                listPermissionNeeded.add(permission)
            }
        }
        if (listPermissionNeeded.isNotEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                listPermissionNeeded.toTypedArray(),
                multiplePermissionId
            )
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray,
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == multiplePermissionId) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                var isGrant = true
                for (element in grantResults) {
                    if (element == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        isGrant = false
                    }
                }
                if (isGrant) {
                    // here all permission granted successfully
                    Toast.makeText(this, "all permission granted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                } else {
                    var someDenied = false
                    for (permission in permissions) {
                        if (
                            !ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)
                        ) {
                            if (
                                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) ==
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                            ) {
                                someDenied = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (someDenied) {
                        // here app Setting open because all permission is not granted
                        // and permanent denied
                        appSettingOpen(this)
                    } else {
                        // here warning permission show
                        warningPermissionDialog(this) { _: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
                            when (which) {
                                DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> checkMultiplePermission()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This code is not mine I just test it with my demo website.
I tried to find solution on android platform but found none.
This the android logcat
Logcat IllegalArgumentException:
024-06-03 17:28:30.668  1264-2123  AlarmManager            com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  alarm window unlikely to be respected [CONTEXT service_id=231 ] (Ask Gemini)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: alarm "NetworkLocationLocator" has short window length
        at bngl.b(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):52)
        at efni.f(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):119)
        at efjs.r(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):107)
        at efjs.f(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):27)
        at efjp.apply(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):19)
        at esdc.d(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):3)
        at esdd.run(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):42)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at bomx.nL(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):1)
        at bomx.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):138)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
--------- beginning of crash
2024-06-03 17:36:43.011  1639-1639  AndroidRuntime          com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp         E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
    Process: com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp, PID: 1639
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://smartappx.site/ac776f6d-9ba9-4d15-ab60-2249b485853b
        at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.<init>(DownloadManager.java:468)
        at com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp.MainActivity.download(MainActivity.kt:236)
        at com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp.MainActivity.loadWebView$lambda$2(MainActivity.kt:148)
        at com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$17rajA2X3B1OvSyO9osdba9FNsQ(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.coding.meet.webviewtoapp.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onDownloadStart(Unknown Source:7)
        at g9.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-447211487:145)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2024-06-03 17:39:19.433  1264-2123  AlarmManager            com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  alarm window unlikely to be respected [CONTEXT service_id=231 ] (Ask Gemini)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: alarm "NetworkLocationLocator" has short window length
        at bngl.b(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):52)
        at efni.f(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):119)
        at efjs.r(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):107)
        at efjs.f(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):27)
        at efjp.apply(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):19)
        at esdc.d(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):3)
        at esdd.run(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):42)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at bomx.nL(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):1)
        at bomx.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@242013041@24.20.13 (190800-633713831):138)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)


Can you post logcat as text with complete error log of IllegalArgumentException ?

@BobSmith I do the solution 1 it downloaded so I stick to this more than solution 2 which I badly follow :c
SOLUTION 1 WORKS
It start to download the pdf file however it failed in the middle of the download.
the file said Download unsuccessful on my emulator notification.

Check it on real device and share error log of unsuccessful download

Please go here sir i stated the logcat. i keep getting report as a spam :c

Please post comments to answers on the answer, not on the question.

I had the similar issue the onDownloadStart param url was appended with blob. It was just in the url so I deleted it and everything works fine.
Solution 1 :
private fun download(
    url: String,
    userAgent: String,
    contentDisposition: String,
    mimeType: String,
    contentLength: Long
) {
    val folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/Image")
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    // Remove the 'blob:' prefix if it exists
    val cleanUrl = url.replace("blob:", "")

    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(cleanUrl))
    request.setMimeType(mimeType)
    val cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(cleanUrl)
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie)
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
    )
    val fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(cleanUrl, contentDisposition, mimeType)
    request.setTitle(fileName)
    request.setNotificationVisibility(
        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
    )
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        "Image/$fileName"
    )
    val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
}


Url that was coming from method -> blob:https://smartappx.site/ac776f6d-9ba9-4d15-ab60-2249b485853b

Url that you had to use -> 
https://smartappx.site/ac776f6d-9ba9-4d15-ab60-2249b485853b


Note : This is the easy way to do it

Solution 2 :
Another solution would be :
1. Fetching the Blob data
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
            "document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function() {" +
            "   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
            "   xhr.open('GET', this.href, true);" +
            "   xhr.responseType = 'blob';" +
            "   xhr.onload = function() {" +
            "       if (xhr.status === 200) {" +
            "           var reader = new FileReader();" +
            "           reader.onload = function() {" +
            "               var base64Data = reader.result.split(',')[1];" +
            "               Android.downloadBlob(base64Data, 'image/jpeg', 'myImage.jpg');" +
            "           };" +
            "           reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);" +
            "       }" +
            "   };" +
            "   xhr.send();" +
            "});" +
        "})();");
    }
});

2. Convert Blob to File using javascript
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void downloadBlob(String base64Data, String mimeType, String fileName) {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64Data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        saveFile(data, mimeType, fileName);
    }
}, "Android");

3. Download the File
private void saveFile(byte[] data, String mimeType, String fileName) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Image");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(folder, fileName);
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        fos.write(data);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Notify the download manager of the new file
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(fileName, fileName, true, mimeType, file.getAbsolutePath(), data.length, true);
}

Use this in case my first solution doesn't work for you, since less code is always best more code is more prone to error and crashes.
